# .net core apply policy to [Authorize] attribute error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to C# and feel like I am losing my mind. I cannot get pass this compilation error. The attribute [Authorize] works fine in my controller. However, when I try to add a Policy restriction. The compiler throws an error. This is the same error for Users and Roles too. The picture below shows the issue and my using statements. Thanks for any insights you may have!!

[image]

This is a sample of code from this project: https://github.com/cornflourblue/dotnet-5-jwt-authentication-api.git

Answer (score 0):

The project had overridden the attribute nvm.

Comment: This should be added as comment rather the answer.